# Dictionary length is equal to 3 but when trying to access an index receiving KeyError

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to parse a json response that looks like this:

```
{
"links": {
    "next": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-08&end_date=2015-09-09&detailed=false&api_key=xxx",
    "prev": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-06&end_date=2015-09-07&detailed=false&api_key=xxx",
    "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&detailed=false&api_key=xxx"
},
"element_count": 22,
"near_earth_objects": {
    "2015-09-08": [
        {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/3726710?api_key=xxx"
            },
            "id": "3726710",
            "neo_reference_id": "3726710",
            "name": "(2015 RC)",
            "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3726710",
            "absolute_magnitude_h": 24.3,
            "estimated_diameter": {
                "kilometers": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 0.0366906138,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 0.0820427065
                },
                "meters": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 36.6906137531,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 82.0427064882
                },
                "miles": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 0.0227984834,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 0.0509789586
                },
                "feet": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 120.3760332259,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 269.1689931548
                }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
            "close_approach_data": [
                {
                    "close_approach_date": "2015-09-08",
                    "close_approach_date_full": "2015-Sep-08 09:45",
                    "epoch_date_close_approach": 1441705500000,
                    "relative_velocity": {
                        "kilometers_per_second": "19.4850295284",
                        "kilometers_per_hour": "70146.106302123",
                        "miles_per_hour": "43586.0625520053"
                    },
                    "miss_distance": {
                        "astronomical": "0.0269230459",
                        "lunar": "10.4730648551",
                        "kilometers": "4027630.320552233",
                        "miles": "2502653.4316094954"
                    },
                    "orbiting_body": "Earth"
                }
            ],
            "is_sentry_object": false
        },
```

}

I am trying to figure out how to parse through to get "miss_distance" dictionary values ? I am unable  to wrap my head around it.

Here is what I have been able to do so far:

1. After I get a Response object from request.get()
   response = request.get(url
2. I convert the response object to json object
   data = response.json() #this returns dictionary object
3. I try to parse the first level of the dictionary:
   for i in data:
     if i == "near_earth_objects":
       dataset1 = data["near_earth_objects"]["2015-09-08"] 
       #this returns the next object which is of type list

Please someone can explain me :
1. How to decipher this response in the first place.
2. How  can I move forward in parsing the response object and get to miss_distance dictionary ?

Please any pointers/help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you include the code you used/error it gave?

Comment: The list has length 1 so just get the first index of it. `data["near_earth_objects"]["2015-09-08"][0]["close_approach_data"]["miss_distance"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data will will have multiple dictionaries for the each date, near earth object, and close approach:

```
near_earth_objects = data['near_earth_objects']
for date in near_earth_objects:
    objects = near_earth_objects[date]
    for object in objects:
        close_approach_data = object['close_approach_data']
        for close_approach in close_approach_data:
            print(close_approach['miss_distance'])
```

Comment: This wouldn't really work, because you cannot iterate the `near_earth_objects` dictionary. You're missing a `.items()` call.

Comment: @abdusco iterating a dictionary gives you its keys. I’m then using the date key to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives you a table of `date, miss_distances` for every object for every date

```
import json
raw_json = '''
{
    "near_earth_objects": {
        "2015-09-08": [
            {
                "close_approach_data": [
                    {
                        "miss_distance": {
                            "astronomical": "0.0269230459",
                            "lunar": "10.4730648551",
                            "kilometers": "4027630.320552233",
                            "miles": "2502653.4316094954"
                        },
                        "orbiting_body": "Earth"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parsed = json.loads(raw_json)

    # assuming this json includes more than one near_earch_object spread across dates
    near_objects = []
    for date, near_objs in parsed['near_earth_objects'].items():
        for obj in near_objs:
            for appr in obj['close_approach_data']:
                o = {
                    'date': date,
                    'miss_distances': appr['miss_distance']
                }
                near_objects.append(o)
    print(near_objects)
```

output:

```
[
  {'date': '2015-09-08', 
   'miss_distances': {
     'astronomical': '0.0269230459', 
     'lunar': '10.4730648551', 
     'kilometers': '4027630.320552233', 
     'miles': '2502653.4316094954'
    }
  }
]
```